# ASP.NET Web API cause exceptions while running on raspberry pi 2 (ARM)

Tags: sqlite, asp.net-core, raspberry-pi, asp.net-web-api2, entity-framework-core

I have coded a Web API in Ubuntu using .NET Core recently and I need to use database to store the application data so that I decided to use EF Core. I ran this project on Ubuntu machine and everything worked appropriately.
I've also tried to run it on my raspberry pi 2 but I wasn't lucky enough to make it work properly. I did the instruction on [this website](https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2018/04/17/hosting-an-asp-net-core-2-application-on-a-raspberry-pi/) and got this output as soon as I tried to access the `api/dooz` on Firefox while accessing my RP through Remmina Remote Desktop.
If the problem is with the database, how can I include the `.db` file to the `iDooz_1/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1/linux-arm/publish` folder to make it work?
How can I solve it?

```
c343@RP:~/publish_idooz1$ ./iDooz_1 
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /home/c343/publish_idooz1
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
      Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HLFUSJJ3S54N", Request id "0HLFUSJJ3S54N:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: Players'.
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.PrepareAndEnumerateStatements(Stopwatch timer)+MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, Boolean buffer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.NoopExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.GetResult[TResult](IEnumerable`1 valueBuffers, Boolean throwOnNullResult)
   at lambda_method(Closure )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ResultEnumerable`1.GetEnumerator()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetFirst[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Boolean& found)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass15_1`1.<CompileQueryCore>b__0(QueryContext qc)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Count[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at iDooz.Controllers.DoozController..ctor() in /home/c343/Documents/iDooz_1/Controllers/DoozController.cs:line 24
   at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<CreateActivator>b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
^CApplication is shutting down...
```

However, `api/values`, the default API in the `webapi` application worked properly and I got the correct output as in I got earlier on Ubuntu.

NOTE: First, this project is generally made to build a Tic Toc Toe and to learn about REstful APIs using `ASP.NET Core Web API`. So, I made a database using Entity Framework called `Dooz.db` and that is in the main directory of the project. Second, I'm doing `dotnet publish -c Release -r linux-arm` because the .NET Core SDK is not available for ARM-Processors.
Third, this is the part of the code in which the terminal had output an error

```
at System.Linq.Queryable.Count[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
       at iDooz.Controllers.DoozController..ctor() in /home/c343/Documents/iDooz_1/Controllers/DoozController.cs:line 24
```

Here is the code:

```
public class DoozController : ControllerBase
    {
        public DoozController()
        {
            if(db.Players.Count() == 0)
            {
                db.Players.Add(new Player { PlayerID = 1, Username = "Alex123", Password = "1234", ProfilePic = "ProfilePics/Alex123.jpg" });
                db.Players.Add(new Player { PlayerID = 2, Username = "Ashkan_007", Password = "12345", ProfilePic = "ProfilePics/Ashkan_007.jpg" });
.
.
.
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
.
.
.
```

Comment: Did you read the error message? It is very clear about what the problem is. If you already have a database file prepared, why don’t you just copy it over to your rpi?

Comment: @poke, thank you man! I thought that `dotenet publish` would have prepared the things for me and no need to edit/add any files to those files it created earlier. I've just copied the db file to the publish folder and finally It worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to copy the database file into publish folder.